# How is the complexity of algorithm to find LPS(Longest prefix which is also a suffix) array is O(n)?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, pattern-matching

Following is my implementation of the algorithm to find the LPS array which is part of the KMP algorithm.

```
public static int[] getLps(String needle)
{
    int[] lps = new int[needle.length()];
    int j = 0;
    lps[j] = 0;

    for (int i=1; i < needle.length(); i++)
    {
        if (needle.charAt(j) == needle.charAt(i))
        {
            j++;
            lps[i] = j;
        }
        else
        {
            while (j != 0)
            {
                j = lps[j-1];

                if (needle.charAt(j) == needle.charAt(i))
                {
                    j++;
                    lps[i] = j;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return lps;
}
```

In the article which I was following for the explanation of KMP algorithm, it was mentioned that the complexity of the logic to find out the LPS array is O(n) which was a little bit confusing for me. As you can see in the above code, there is an inner while loop inside the for loop. In the worst case, the inner while will run for j number of iterations. Shouldn't this cause our complexity to be greater than O(n)?

One way I can think that justifies the O(n) complexity is that in the inner while loop we are not repeating our whole logic. We are just reducing the value of j till it reaches 0 or matches with the value at ith index. So this while loop is considered as the part of a single iteration from outer for loop and in the end complexity of our algorithm becomes O(n).

Can anyone confirm this or provide some more clarification on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is `j`? This is length of current prefix.

At every step we make suffix longer by one, and we may get coinciding prefix longer by one. But prefix length might become smaller, and sometimes zero. But if we make prefix of zero length, and will expand it one char-by-one, we have to perform a lot of operations. Instead this algorithm uses smart optimization - prefix length is diminished by one to reuse already calculated information.

The most important moment - **overall number of prefix reductions cannot exceed string length** - that is why complexity is linear.

Comment: the overall number of prefix reductions cannot exceed string length which means in the worst case our algorithm will perform 2n operations. So our complexity becomes O(2n) which is still a linear time complexity and thus can be represented as O(n). Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Yes, you are right - O(2n), O(100n) and any O(kn) where k is constant are equal to O(n), constants are not important.